# How to alter HTML code with different combinations of button presses

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button, combinations

I wrote some code consisting of three buttons and a paragraph.
The paragraph says, "Hello my name is Dolly." and the buttons give you the choice to do one of three things to Dolly. You can either say hello, hug, or kill them, and these buttons give a response respectively. However is it possible to press a combination of buttons for a different response? For example, if I pressed the button to kill Dolly, then the button to hug Dolly, could I make it say something about hugging a dead body? If so, how?

Comment: by keeping a variable for dolly's state.

Comment: please show your code it will be useful for dealing with your question

Comment: @Chewynugget did you benefit from the answers?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal Yes, I did!

Comment: Generally, questions about code should include code you have tried and where you struggle with your solution. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My bad, I'll be sure to include my code next time @MarkSchultheiss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by keeping a state object for dolly.

```
var dolly = {
  is_alive: true,
  hugCount: 0,
  helloCount: 0,
  message: function() {
    if(!this.is_alive) {
      //whatever you want to print if dolly's dead.
    } 
    if(this.hugCount) {
      //whatever for a certain number of hug counts.
    }        
    if(this.helloCount) {
      //whatever for a certain number of hello counts.
    }

  },
  kill: function(){
    if(this.is_alive){
      this.is_alive = false;
      return this.message();
    }
  }
};
```

You can keep adding more functionality if this is a simulation game prototype. just add more functions to the object, if you need to add more people like tina or james, you can make a constructor too.

```
var Person = function() {
  this.is_alive = true,
  this.hugCount = 0,
  this.helloCount = 0,
};
Person.prototype.message = function() {
    if(!this.is_alive) {
      //whatever you want to print if dolly's dead.
    } 
    if(this.hugCount) {
      //whatever for a certain number of hug counts.
    }        
    if(this.helloCount) {
      //whatever for a certain number of hello counts.
    }

};
Person.prototype.kill = function(){
    if(this.is_alive){
      this.is_alive = false;
      return this.message();
    }
};
Person.prototype.hello = function() {
  this.helloCount+= 1;
  return this.message();
}
```

Now you can just spawn as many dollys you want with the same functionality!

```
var dolly = new Person();
dolly.kill(); //YOU DIED!
```

**EDIT 1**

As per the suggestion of Norman Bentley, you can also use array to keep a track of user's interaction with "dolly".

```
var Person = function() {
  this.is_alive = true,
  this.hugCount = 0,
  this.helloCount = 0,
  this.interaction =  []
};

var ACTIONS = {"HUG":0x01,"KILL":0x02,"GREET":0x03};
// Using hexes in an attempt to save bytes not sure what's the best way to do this!

Person.prototype.interaction = function(action) {
  // you can use an array of constants for your actions.
  this.interaction.push(action);
}

Person.prototype.kill = function() {
 this.interaction(ACTIONS.KILL);
 this.is_alive = false;
 return this.message();
}
```

**EDIT 2**

To embed this along with HTML, refer to this JS fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/3jvbqm9a/

Comment: Nice post! use count as above if the order of events does not matter.  If it does, you may need to use an array.

Comment: @NormanBentley Thanks and right! I will add an edit for this.

Comment: Thank you so much @AmreshVenugopal

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new at coding. How can I attach this script to an HTML button?

Comment: I'll add it in a while. @Chewynugget

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal Thank you for all your help, I do appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you could.  Create a variable/array for dolly in Javascript.  Each time you perform an action to dolly, add it to this array.  Read the array each time and decide what your response should be.